# Haskell, multiplying Int and Float within a function

Tags: haskell, types

Why is it that in ghci I can enter:

```
5.0 * (3 - 1)
> 10.0
```

But if I try and create a function in a .hs file and load it in:

```
test :: Float -> Int -> Int -> Float
test a b c = a * (b - c)
```

I am hit with an error? "Couldnt match expected type 'Float' against inferred type 'Int'?
And how can I write a function that takes in one floating point and 2 integer arguments and performs the above operation on them?

I am using ghci v6.12.1 if that makes a difference...

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Numeric literals (i.e. just typing a number in Haskell code) are not some fixed type. They are polymorphic. They need to be evaluated in some context that requires them to have a concrete type.

So the expression `5.0 * (3 - 1)` is *not* multiplying an `Int` by a `Float`. `5.0` has to be some `Fractional` type, `3` and `1` are each some `Num` type. `3 - 1` means that the 3 and the 1 both have to be the *same* `Num` type, but we still don't (yet) have any more constraints about which particular one it is; the result of the subtraction is the same type.

The `*` means both arguments have to be the same type, and the result will be the same type too. Since `5.0` is some `Fractional` type, the `(3 - 1)` must be too. We already knew that `3`, `1`, and `(3 - 1)` had to be some `Num` type but all `Fractional` types are also `Num` types, so this requirements are not in conflict.

The end result is that the whole expression `5.0 * (3 - 1)` is some type that is `Fractional`, and the `5.0`, `3`, and `1` are all the same type. You can use the `:t` command in GHCi to see this:

```
Prelude> :t 5.0 * (3 - 1)
5.0 * (3 - 1) :: Fractional a => a
```

But to actually *evaluate* that expression, we need to do so for some concrete type. If we were evaluating this and passing it to some function that required `Float`, `Double`, or some other particular `Fractional` type then Haskell would pick that one. If we just evaluate the expression with no other context requiring it to be a particular type, Haskell has some defaulting rules to automatically choose one for you (if the defaulting rules don't apply it will instead give you a type error about ambiguous type variables).

```
Prelude> 5.0 * (3 - 1)
10.0
Prelude> :t it
it :: Double
```

Above I've evaluated `5.0 * (3 - 1)`, then asked for the type of the magic `it` variable which GHCi always binds to the last value it evaluated. This tells me that GHCi has defaulted my `Fractional a => a` type to just `Double`, in order to compute that the value of the expression was `10.0`. In doing that evaluation, it only ever multipled (and subtracted) `Double`s, it never multiplied a `Double` by an `Int`.

---

Now, that's what's going on when you attempt to multiple numeric *literals* that look like they might be of different types. But your `test` function isn't multiplying literals, it's multiplying variables of particular known types. In Haskell you can't multiply an `Int` by a `Float` because the `*` operator has type `Num a => a -> a -> a` - it takes two values of the same numeric type and gives you a result that is that type. You can multiply an `Int` by an `Int` to get an `Int`, or a `Float` by a `Float` to get a `Float`. You can't multiply an `Int` by a `Float` to get a `???`.

Other languages support this sort of operation only by implicitly inserting calls to conversion functions under some circumstances. Haskell *never* implicitly converts between types, but it has the conversion functions. You just need to call them explicitly if you want them to be called. This would do the trick:

```
test :: Float -> Int -> Int -> Float
test a b c = a * fromIntegral (b - c)
```

Answer (score 6):

Try the following instead:

```
test :: Float -> Int -> Int -> Float
test a b c = a * fromIntegral (b - c)
```

Why does this work?

1. Since `b` and `c` are both `Int`s the expression `(b - c)` is also an `Int`.
2. The type signature of `(*)` is `Num a => a -> a -> a`.
3. Because `a` is of type `Float` Haskell updates the type signature of `(a*)` to `Float -> Float`.
4. However since `(b - c)` is an `Int` and not a `Float` Haskell would complain if you tried doing `a * (b - c)`.
5. The type signature of `fromIntegral` is `(Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`.
6. Hence the type signature of `fromIntegral (b - c)` is `Num b => b`.
7. Since `Float` is an instance of typeclass `Num` you're allowed to do `a * fromIntegral (b - c)` because the type signature of `(*)` is `Num a => a -> a -> a`.
8. The result, from the type signature of `test` evaluates to `Float`.

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `fromIntegral` on the integers before multiplying by the floats.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Converting_numbers

In GHCI, the numbers aren't assumed to be floats or ints until you use them. (e.g: at run time). That works out better for REPL-style development.

In the compiler proper,  <strike>there isn't any automatic coercion. It</strike>  **it** sees the multiplication assumes that the two values must belong to a type-class that supports multiplication. e.g: multiplying ints , or multiplying floats. As you didn't use any other explicitly typed functions, it assumed ints. That assumption then differs with your (optional) type signature.

Comment: "In the compiler proper, there isn't any automatic coercion" - but there is a coercion of number literals, the same as in ``ghci``.

Comment: ah, right. and literal coercion doesn't come into play here. I'll edit.

Comment: You're actually much more likely to run into problems with numbers being assumed to be floats or ints in GHCi than you are in compiled modules. In either case, the way the numbers are used across the whole "compilation unit" is taken into account when figuring out the type of the numbers, but in GHCi the "compilation unit" is each input line taken one at a time! So the way numeric types are defaulted isn't done for the benefit of REPL-style development; it's actually pretty painful in the REPL.

Comment: I even often make an alias for `fromIntegral` for brevity:

    `int :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b
    int = fromIntegral`

Answer (score 3):

Your `test`  function was more general, before you add a signature:

```
> let test a b c = a * (b - c)
> :t test
  test :: Num a => a -> a -> a -> a
```

You could restrict it, but all types must be the same:

```
test :: Fractional a => a -> a -> a -> a   -- some real types
test :: Integral   a => a -> a -> a -> a   -- all integer types
test :: Float -> Float -> Float -> Float  
test :: Int   -> Int   -> Int   -> Int   

test :: Int   -> Float -> Float -> Float  --wrong
```

By the way, `2` isn't `Int` and `0.2` isn't `Float`, let ask `gchi`:

```
> :t 2
 2 :: Num a => a
> :t 0.2
 0.2 :: Fractional a => a
```