# Couldn't match expexted type Double with actual Int

Tags: haskell, math, haskell-platform

I tried to calculate ch value without using `cosh` function.

```
ch :: Double -> Int -> Double
ch' :: Double -> Int -> Integer -> Double -> Double

fac :: Integer -> Integer
fac 0 = 1
fac k | k > 0 = k * fac (k-1)

taylor :: Double -> Int -> Double
taylor x n = ((x^2*n))/ (2*(fac n))

ch x iter = ch' x iter 0 1
ch' x iter n sum | iter == fromIntegral n = sum
                 | iter /= fromIntegral n = ch' x iter (n+1) (sum + (taylor x n))
```

But I have error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `Double` with actual type `Integer`
In the second argument of `(*)`, namely `n`
In the first argument of `(/)`, namely `((x ^ 2 * n))`
```

and

```
Couldn't match expected type `Double` with actual type `Integer`
In the second argument of `(*)`, namely `fac n`
In the first argument of `(/)`, namely `(2 *(fac n))`
```

I guess I tried to divide Double, but I've got Integer. How I can solve this problem?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Haskell, multiplying Int and Float within a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19019093/haskell-multiplying-int-and-float-within-a-function)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the arithmetic operators `+`, `*`, and `-` have the type

```
Num a => a -> a -> a
```

Where the `Num a` has to be *the same* `a` on both sides of the operator.  Both `Double` and `Integer` implement `Num`, but you can not add them directly.  Instead, you have to convert your values to the correct type.  Since you're returning a `Double` from `taylor`, I'm guessing that you want to convert your `Integer` values to `Double` values.  You can do this easily with `fromInteger` (which is actually a function in the `Num` typeclass):

```
taylor x n = (x^2 * fromInteger n) / (2 * fromInteger (fac n))
```

Notice that you have to convert both `Integer` values in this computation.  If this looks a bit cluttered to you, you can always use a `where` clause:

```
taylor x n = (x^2 * n')/ (2 * facn)
    where
        n' = fromInteger n
        facn = fromInteger $ fac n
```